# Calling a function from Angular.js Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Following is a simple Angular.js code snippet :**

```
XApp.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, GetProductsForIndex, $http) {
    console.log('Step 1');
    var Obj = new Object();

    Obj.PAGEINDEX = 1;
    Obj.PAGESIZE = 25;
    Obj.SPNAME = "index_get_products";
    Obj.PAGECOUNT = null;
    Obj.COUNTRYCODE = 'in'

    $scope.data = GetProductsForIndex.query({ parameters : Obj }, function () {
        console.log($scope.data);
        $scope.products = $scope.data;
    });

})


XApp.factory('GetProductsForIndex', function ($resource) {
    console.log('Step 2');
    return $resource('api/index/:object?type=json', {}, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true } });
});
```

I am trying to implement infinite scroll using http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

In their demo here http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html they are calling the `loadMore()` function.

**In my case i want to execute the following on scroll :**

```
$scope.data = GetProductsForIndex.query({ parameters : Obj }, function () {
            console.log($scope.data);
            $scope.products = $scope.data;
        });
```

and increment the pageIndex `Obj.PAGEINDEX = 1` by 1. How am i supposed to do that? Today is my 3rd day with Angular.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a loadMore function like this inside your controller ,

```
XApp.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, GetProductsForIndex, $http) {
    function loadData($scope, obj){
           $scope.products.push( GetProductsForIndex.query({ parameters : Obj }, function ()                       {           

            }));
     } 

 console.log('Step 1');
    var Obj = new Object();
     $scope.products=[];
    Obj.PAGEINDEX = 1;
    Obj.PAGESIZE = 25;
    Obj.SPNAME = "index_get_products";
    Obj.PAGECOUNT = null;
    Obj.COUNTRYCODE = 'in'

    loadData($scope, Obj);
})
```